# Gibbs Sampler - Sample mean convergence

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, convergence, gibbs, markov-chain

To simulate from the posterior distribution $p(\theta|Y)$ where $\theta = (\mu,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$, I run a Gibbs sampler to draw approximately random values from $p(\theta|Y)$. 
This Gibbs sampler returns as output $$\lbrace \mu^{(n)}, \lambda_1^{(n)}, \lambda_2^{(n)} \rbrace_{n=1}^{N}$$ (after burn-in).

If interested in the parameter $\lambda_1$, to estimate this parameter $\lambda_1$, I use the statistic : $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda_1^{(i)}$$ This is the naive Monte Carlo estimator that approximates the expectation of $\lambda_1$ by the strong law of large numbers (the sample has to be iid to make this work).

My question: does the Gibbs sampler produce an iid sample from the posterior $p(\theta|Y)$ ?

Comment: Gibbs sampling (and MCMC more generally) produces *dependent* values, so no, they're not iid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validations for both the convergence of the Gibbs Markov chain and of the empirical average based on this Markov chain are (both) called *ergodic theorems*.

> For a Harris positive chain $(X_n)$, with invariant distribution
>   $\pi$, an atom $\alpha$ is *ergodic* if $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\;
>   |K^n(\alpha,\alpha)-\pi(\alpha)|=0 \;. $$ In the countable case, the
>   existence of an *ergodic* atom is, in fact, sufficient to establish
>   convergence according to the total variation norm, $$
>   \|\mu_1-\mu_2\|_{TV} = \sup_A \; |\mu_1(A)-\mu_2(A)| . $$ **Proposition 6.48:**
>   If $(X_n)$ is Harris positive on $\mathcal{X}$ and denumerable, and if
>   there exists an ergodic atom $\alpha\subset \mathcal{X}$, then, for
>   every $x \in \mathcal{X} $, $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \;
>   \|K^n(x,\cdot)-\pi\|_{TV} = 0 \;. $$ (extract from [Monte Carlo
>   Statistical Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441919392) (2004), p.231)

and

> **Proposition 6.63:** If $(X_n)$ has a $\sigma$-finite invariant measure $\pi$, the following two statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. If $f,g\in L^1(\pi)$ with $\int g(x) d\pi(x)\neq 0$, then$$\lim_{N
>         \rightarrow \infty} \; \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N f(X_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^N g(X_i)} ={\int f(x) \text{d}\pi(x)
>         \over \int g(x) \text{d}\pi(x)} \;.$$
> 2. The Markov chain $(X_n)$ is Harris recurrent.
>
> (extract from [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441919392) (2004), p.241)

None of those results requires i.i.d. sampling.

Comment: so that this sample mean of the single parameter $\lambda_1$ converges to the expectation value (a posterori mean - bayes estimator in this case) follows directly from the ergodic theorem for the gibbs markovchain ? i am a little bit confused because in your book you write the ergodic theorem for the whole chain $\mathbf{X} = (X_1,X_2,X_3)$ but i am only interested in a single one. But follows this fact too ?

Comment: If you pick $f(\lbrace \mu^{(n)}, \lambda_1^{(n)}, \lambda_2^{(n)} \rbrace)=\lambda_1^{(n)}$, this is a particular function of the chain.

Comment: not at all: the subchains like $\{\lambda_1^{(n)}\}_n$ are more complex objects than the chain itself and most often not Markov chains per se, but only hidden Markov chains.

Comment: what means hidden markov chain in this context ? because in my thesis (that i ve already handed in :( ) i wrote that the subchains are markov chains from this 3-stage gibbs-sampler (that in general holds for the 2-stage case) ! so is there a opportunity to save a well deserved grade :) ?

Comment: In general, the sub-chains of a three-stage Gibbs sampler are _not_ Markov chains themselves. This is why we distinguish the two-stage case in our book, as the only one that produces sub-Markov-chains that are again Markov. What I mean by hidden Markov is tautological: $\{\lambda_1^{(n)}\}_n$ is a part of a Markov chain...